# Are there any guidelines to follow when choosing number of processes with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm just getting my feet wet with multiprocessing (and it's totally awesome!), but I was wondering if there was any guidelines to selecting number of processes?  Is it just based on number of cores on the server? Is it somehow based on the application your running (number of loops, how much cpu it uses, etc)? etc...how do I decide how many processes to spawn? Right now, I'm just guessing and add/removing processes but it would be great if there was some kind of guideline or best practice.

Another question, I know what happens if I add too few (program is slow) but what if I add 'too many'?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If all of your threads/processes are indeed CPU-bound, you should run as many processes as the CPU reports cores. Due to [HyperThreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), each physical CPU cores may be able to present multiple virtual cores. Call [`multiprocessing.cpu_count`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count) to get the number of virtual cores.

If only *p* of 1 of your threads is CPU-bound, you can adjust that number by multiplying by *p*. For example, if half your processes are CPU-bound (*p* = 0.5) and you have two CPUs with 4 cores each and 2x HyperThreading, you should start  0.5 * 2 * 4 * 2 = 8 processes.

If you have too few process, your application will run slower than expected. If your application scales perfectly and is only CPU-bound (i.e. is 10 times faster when executed on 10 times the amount of cores), this means you the speed is slower in relation. For example, if your system calls for 8 processes, but you only initiate 4, you'll only use half of the processing capacity and take twice as long. Note that in practice, no application scales perfectly, but some (ray tracing, video encoding) are pretty close.

If you have too many processes, the synchronization overhead will increase. If your program is little to none synchronization overhead, this won't impact the overall runtime, but may make other programs appear slower than they are unless you set your processes to a lower priority. Excessive numbers of processes (say, 10000) are fine in theory if your OS has a good scheduler. In practice, virtually any synchronization will make the overhead unbearable.

If you're not sure whether your application is CPU-bound and/or perfectly scaling, simply observe system load with different thread counts. You want the system load to be slightly under 100%, or the more precise [uptime](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uptime) to be the number of virtual cores.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  Didn't know all that.  What if there is a bit of non-cpu bound parts in the app. For example, alot of cpu calculations, but then final result is saved to file or database.  Does that mean I should create more processes as some have to wait for the final network(database) or disk write(file write)?

Comment: @Lostsoul In general, yes if the share of disk-bound activity is significant. If you're writing one short summation file (say, the image after raytracing a complicated scene), this effect is negligible. If your application reads and writes lots of data, you should indeed increase the number of processes. Updated the answer with one paragraph: If you're not sure, try it out!

Comment: Just to add to the observation part: you obviously want to avoid the CPU utilisation increasing because of synchronisation overhead. So, when doing the experiment, you should measure both system load, and your application throughput.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely based on what the application does. If it's CPU-heavy, the number of cores is a sane starting point. If it's IO-heavy, mulitple processes won't help performance anyway. If it's mostly CPU with occasional IO (e.g. PNG optimisation), you can run a few processes more than the number of cores.

The only way to know for certain is to run your application with some realistic input and check the resource utilisation. If you have CPU time to spare, add more worker processes.